# How to upload file on mac with selenium java

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, awtrobot

Hello I want to upload a png file to the message
How do I do this?
When I try the robot it doesn't work
Please help me

The below-mentioned script is written as an example

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiQl3.png)

[choosefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAToG.png)

[choosenfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qizFI.png)

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), ' Messages ')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#attach_file_photo")).click();

        String filename = "/Users/usr/eclipse-workspace/TestScript/src/test/resources/picture/Seleniumautomationtesting.png";

        StringSelection s = new StringSelection(filename);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s, null);

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

            
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.delay(1000 * 4);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnsubmit")).click();
```

Comment: If you have input element with`type=file`, you can just execute `input.sendKeys(file);`

Comment: there is not input or type